# Does anyone have a solution to gmail's lack of true shared inboxes?

Tags: gmail

Our organization uses both Google Workspace for Non-Profits and Microsoft Business Premium. Our mail is hosted through Google. We are having issues as we grow with the lack of true shared inboxes in Google. Gmail's shared inboxes are managed by a user and not from the admin panel since they are actually delegating user access. We want to continue to use shared email addresses for business functions for continuity purposes. I am interested to hear from other IT people that use gmail at 100+ employee sized businesses, how you deal with this issue. I know we could solve this problem by using Microsoft Exchange instead but I need to make sure I've exhausted all of my options with gmail first.

Answer (score 1):

Double checking that you've enabled access to mailbox delegation on your Workspace control panel: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en

With that feature on a shared inbox like hr@companyname.com works well.

If you'd like a shared inbox on steroids for Google Workspace check out Hiverhq.com. We've switched 3 companies so far from Office 365 to Google Workspace for its simple to use feature set tightly integrated to the gmail inbox.

Disclosure: We're a Google Cloud Partner, Microsoft Silver Partner, and HiverHQ partner. We frequently migrate or merge customers across the Google and Microsoft platforms to best meet their needs.

Comment: We use mailbox delegation but having to switch between inboxes is a pain and the lack of admin control is a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Workspace for Non-Profits and Microsoft Business Premium

In your case I would think to maybe switch the email provider to O365 if you need more setting like in Exchange. The why is Microsoft already give 300 free Business basic license to registered OSBL (and 10 Business Premium). The shared mailbox will work out of the box hosted that way, and it would not cost you money to do, you just need to do the [paper work](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/nonprofits/eligibility?activetab=pivot1%3Aprimaryr4) with Microsoft to make you eligible for that.

Comment: We already have Microsoft licenses we just don't use Exchange. I would like to switch to Exchange but I need to show that it is out best option. That is why I am looking others organizations that use Google, so I can find out how they deal with the lack of true shared inboxes so I can make my case.